# Copy file from remote server using PHP over HTTP

Tags: php

I want to copy a file using PHP over http from a link in this format

http://myserver.com/?id=1234

if I open the link, the download of the file starts ...

So I assume that server redirects to a .mp3 file to start the download.

So how to copy/download the file from the remote server to to my server (localhost)?

Comment: Could you show us how you tried to accomplish that? (code)

Answer (score 6):

Just to gove an example of what Victor is tlking about with cURL:

```
$options = array(
  CURLOPT_FILE => '/local/path/for/file.mp3',
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_URL => 'http://myserver.com/?id=1234',

);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: As I can see in your example, the path to the .mp3 file is set, yet I don't know the url of the .mp3 file!

Comment: thats the path you want to download it too... you dont need to know the path to the file on the remote server, as long as the url is returning the file.

Comment: +1 for teaching me about `curl_setopt_array()`! Had never heard about it before now.

Comment: `CURLOPT_FILE` has to be a file HANDLE not a filename

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming here that the remote server sends the complete file over HTTP. You could use a library such as [`curl`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) to send an HTTP request and store the received data as a file (using `CURLOPT_FILE`).

If your local PHP server is correctly configured, you can also use [`copy`](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php) to copy from a remote URL to a local path.

Comment: Can you provide me with examples using both methods?

Comment: For the second method, there's an example on the page I linked to. I'm in a good mood, so I'll provide a direct link (http://fr.php.net/manual/en/function.copy.php#83955) but you might want work on your documentation skills.

Answer (score 0):

$handle = fopen("http://www.example.com/", "rb");
$contents = '';
while (!feof($handle)) {
  $contents .= fread($handle, 8192);
}
fclose($handle);

from

http://php.net/manual/en/function.fread.php

Answer (score 0):

Try using a notification callback (read here for mor informations http://www.php.net/manual/function.stream-notification-callback.php)

e.g. you could to this if you like to copy:

```
function stream_notification_callback($notification_code, $severity, $message, $message_code, $bytes_transferred, $bytes_max)
{
  if($notification_code == STREAM_NOTIFY_PROGRESS)
  {
    // save $bytes_transferred and $bytes_max to file or database
  }
}


$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_params($ctx, array("notification" => "stream_notification_callback"));
copy($remote_url,$Local_target,$ctx);
```

Another PHP file could read the saved $bytes_transferred and $bytes_max and show a nice progress bar.